# is there a faster way to request data from an REST api?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, rest

i'm trying to speed up the code below. At the moment its taking about 15 mins to run....

The data source i'm accessing only returns 1000 lines per page, there is an unknown number of lines so i'm left iterating thought pages to get the full data set.

i'm unsure why this is so slow, data source is running on a local server.

Any help would be great!

def calcreadings(calc_elements_id, unit_of_time, length_of_data, size=1000, page=1):
    try:
    # imports required libarys
        import requests
        import pandas as pd

```
    canary_server, access_token = config()
    calc_elements_id = str(calc_elements_id)
    length_of_data = str(length_of_data)
    unit_of_time = str(unit_of_time)
    # sets up the requeste to collect data from the API

    pages_check = page

    # loops over the pages in the api

    while pages_check > 0:
        request = requests.get(canary_server
                            + 'calcelements/' + calc_elements_id
                            + '/data/?'
                            + 'periodType=' + unit_of_time
                            + '&active=false'
                            + '&_size=' + str(size)
                            + '&_page=' + str(page)
                            + '&_sort= Id DESC'
                            + '&periodLength=' + str(length_of_data)
                            + '&access_token=' + access_token)

        calc_readings_check = pd.read_json(request.text)
        if len(calc_readings_check) != 0:
            if page == 1:
                # loads the data from the API in to Pandas Data Frame
                calc_readings = calc_readings_check
            else:
                # loads the data from the API in to Pandas Data Frame and appends
                calc_readings = calc_readings.append(calc_readings_check)
            page += 1
        else:
            pages_check = 0
    try:
        calc_readings['calc_elements_id'] = int(calc_elements_id)
    except NameError:
        calc_readings = ''
    return calc_readings
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Hi. Can you provide more information, as to the number of records returned during the 15 mins? How does your local service compile and return the data (is it calculated on the fly or retried from a database)? Is it an option for your Python code to access the datasource directly rather than the API?

Comment: What is this `&_size=` url parameter? aren't you setting it to 1000 by any chance? what if you don't set it at all? the API might return all the records.

Comment: Tried that it returns 1000 default